# Problems with my PHP script - newbie fails?

Tags: php

Hey Guys I have a Problem with my PHP Script it doesn't work ...
I don't know why it doesn't work or which skills I have to improove.

I would be thankfull for help

The Code is here : http://pastebin.com/gkFBEJS0

Thanks a loot
Chris

Comment: What exactly does not work? And why didn't you post the code directly here?

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Wow, three comments submitted in four seconds ...

Comment: Is there anything that does happen? Or is your script just not producing anything? Do you get any error messages? If not, do `display_errors(E_ALL);` on the first line of any script to display all errors.

Comment: Seems to me like a new record... :D

Answer (score 1):

Your first fatal error is easy, you are calling `$db->query($db_var_one)` and `$db` is not an object.

It looks like you need `$db_cnct_one` instead.

Comment: @ChrisR I don´t know what that´s supposed to mean, but I do know that in the scope of your function, `$db` is not defined.